# APNS PHP Not Sending Notifications

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I've set up and APNS Provider Server using PHP. I connect to Apple's APNS Server with no errors, and the script seems to run fine, cycling through all the devices and sending the payload. However, notifications aren't being received on the devices that have subscribed to notifications. Can someone please help me find the error in my code?

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
echo "Posted Message: $message<br />";

$message = str_replace("'", "\'", $message);
echo "Formatted message: $message<br />";

$title = $_POST['title'];
$title = str_replace("'", "\'", $title);
echo "Formatted Title: $title<br />";

$category = $_POST['category'];
echo "Category: $category<br />";

$alert = array('title' => "$title", 'body' => "$message");
foreach ($alert as $key => $value){
    echo "Key: $key Value: $value<br />";
}

ini_set("display_errors",1);

$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'apns.pem';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
if ($error!="" || $errorString!=""){
    echo "Error Connecting: $error : $errorString<br />";
}
else{
    echo "No Error Connecting<br />";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO notifications (`title`, `message`, `category`) VALUES (\"$title\", \"$message\", \"$category\")";
echo "Insert Query: $query<br />";

$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$query = "SELECT * FROM notifications ORDER BY notification_id DESC";
$result931 = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = $result931->fetch_assoc();
$notification_id = $row[notification_id];

$query = "SELECT * FROM category_subscriptions WHERE category_id='$category' ORDER BY device_id";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
echo "Subscriber Query: $query<br />";
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $device_id = $row[device_id];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE device_id='$device_id' ORDER BY device_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $deviceToken = $r[device_token];
        $badge = $r[badge_value] + 1;
        if ($r[accepts_alerts]==1) {
            if ($r[accepts_badges]==1) {
                if ($r[accepts_sounds]==1) {
                    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $alert, 'badge' => $badge, 'sound' => 'default');
                } else {
                    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $alert, 'badge' => $badge);
                }
            }
            else if ($r[accepts_sounds]==1) {
                    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $alert, 'sound' => 'default');
            } 
            else {
                $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $alert);
            }
            $payload1 = json_encode($payload);
            echo "Payload: $payload1<br />";

            echo "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sending to Device Token: $deviceToken<br />";
            $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload1)) . $payload1;
            echo "APNS Message: $apnsMessage<br />";
            fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
            $query6 = "UPDATE devices SET badge_value = $badge WHERE device_id='$device_id'";
            $result6 = mysqli_query($connection,$query6);
            $query7 = "INSERT INTO notification_map (`device_id`, `notification_id`, `viewed`) VALUES ($device_id, $notification_id, \"false\")";
            $result7 = mysqli_query($connection,$query7);
        }
    }
}
fclose($apns);
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using a production certificate?  And have you tried using one of the APNS test apps to make sure?

Comment: The certificate I'm using is a production certificate, however, I'll be honest, I'm not sure I fully understand the certificate creation process. In development mode, my app was sending a notification to the first device in the loop, but then failing to send with subsequent devices.  I assume it's doing the same thing here, but can't tell for sure since my device is not the first one in the loop.

Comment: Just verified, it is sending the notification to the first device in the loop, but fails on all subsequent devices.

Answer (score 2):

Perform following steps:
 1. Check if pem file is valid or not.
 2. check if port 2195 is open on your server or not.

### 3. if your pem file is of development mode the use "ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195" to connect to apns otherwise if your pem file is of production mode the use "ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195" .

4. check if passpharas is correct.

check this sample code:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'fefb03ba6adcea310cf3f455dae16fec4f63b4ba4d96103c20d594a04efd7c2a';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'Welcome@1';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
 exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'title' => 'testing title'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n',    strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
 echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
 echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Shouldn't I get an error when connecting if the PEM file is invalid or the port is not open? Is there a way to test the PEM file to see if it's valid? If I remember correctly, I didn't set a passphrase for my certificate and the one I'm using is supposed to be a production certificate, although as I mention in my reply to TheValyreanGroup, I'm not sure I have a handle on certificates as much as I should...

Comment: I just went back and looked at the parameters for the stream_socket_client call. I noticed I've got it set to timeout after 2 seconds. Perhaps that's the issue.  I'll adjust that and see if it fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further reading of the documentation, I believe I have figured out my problem. I had one database table that held the device tokens for both development and production versions of the app. Apparently when trying to send a production notification it was closing the connection after sending a development device token. I'm not sure why the fwrite command wasn't sending errors after the connection closed, but since I deleted the development device tokens from the database table, it appears to be working now.

Comment: Hi Richard, you safe my life~ I have same issue like you and stuck over 3-4 days. After i removed all dev tokens, I can receive notification now~ thx